# Binding Label textProperty in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I have this code in initialize method JavaFX:

```
montantPayeProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
labelMontantPaye.textProperty().bind(montantPayeProperty.asString());
```

`montantPayeProperty` is a `DoubleProperty`, and `labelMontantPaye` is a `Label`.

And I have a button when I click, this method is called :

```
public void majMontantPaye(Double montantPaye) {
   this.montantPayeProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(montantPaye);
}
```

The problem is that my `Label labelMontantPaye` is not refreshed automatically with `montantPaye` when I click in the button. Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public void majMontantPaye(Double montantPaye) {
  this.montantPayeProperty.setValue(montantPaye);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call

```
labelMontantPaye.textProperty().bind(montantPayeProperty.asString());
```

you are binding the object pointed by the pointer stored in the `textProperty` of the `Label` to the object pointed by the pointer stored in `montantPayeProperty`.

When you call

```
this.montantPayeProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(montantPaye);
```

the pointer stored in the `montantPayeProperty` will point to a new object, but the binding will still be active between the old object and the `textProperty`. The old object is unmodified, therefore this property does not get updated.

You should not set the pointer to a new object, but set the value stored in the currently pointed object by calling:

```
montantPayeProperty.setValue(montantPaye);
```

or by

```
montantPayeProperty.set(montantPaye);
```

Comment: This is an informative answer that doesn't just answer the question, but provides some background and additional knowledge. Very good :-)

Answer (score 2):

You replace the property, in your setter, so the `Label`'s `text` property is bound to a different property instance.

A property usually should not be replaced once it's created. Instead the value stored in the property should be modified. The standard for a property `value` (non-lazy initialisation) would be

```
private final DoubleProperty value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

public DoubleProperty valueProperty() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value.set(value);
}

public double getValue() {
    return value.get();
}
```